# combine several lines from json

Tags: java, json, parsing, selenide

in the test I have to get the product version and build number but they are in different lines, and have an extra suffix that needs to be removed.
I can not cope with this task, can you help?

```
JsonObject versionConfig = read("config","version",user.userName, user.password);
version=versionConfig.get("buildNumber").getAsString();
```

json answer

```
{
  "version": "1.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "branch": "1111",
  "buildNumber": "666",
  "date": "01.01.2020"
}
```

everyone understands what I am getting only version=666

but in the end I need to get

```
version=1.1.666
```

do not swear, I worked as a system administrator for 3 years, and I'm only learning Java, and with parsing, Json did not work at all, this is the best that I could

Comment: need delete word SNAPSHOT from value "version"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your version and replace "Version" by your buildNumber:

```java
String version = versionConfig.get("version").getAsString();
String buildNumber = versionConfig.get("buildNumber").getAsString();
String result = version.replace("Version",buildNumber);
//1.1-Version => 1.1-666
```

Comment: not exactly as needed
in json answer 

'{
  "version": "1.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "branch": "1111",
  "buildNumber": "666",
  "date": "01.01.2020"
}'

(version - SNAPSHOT)
and result - //1.1-Version => 1.1-666
i need 1.1.666

Comment: ```version.replace("-Version","."+buildNumber);```

Comment: I was wrong
version": "1.1-SNAPSHOT", (NOT Version)
  "branch": "1111",
  "buildNumber": "666",
  "date": "01.01.2020"

Comment: ```version.replace("-SNAPSHOT","."+buildNumber);``` can't you adapt to what's written lmao

Comment: I'm trying to))

Comment: Thanks bro, now i understand how make replace